# How to make a table of contents that can be scrolled manually in RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr

I have been making a summary report of data using the `rmdformats` package in RMarkdown. I have been using the "floating table of contents" option, however I have noticed that in sufficiently large documents (my document has at least 15 first order headers due to its nature) the later parts of the document are cut off and cannot easily be selected without manually scrolling to them. These are the settings I have been using...

```
output:
  rmdformats::html_clean:
    highlight: haddock
    toc: TRUE
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: TRUE
    number_sections: TRUE
    thumbnails: FALSE
    code_folding: show
    df_print: paged
    DT: datatable
```

I have been trying to figure out a way to add a more manual scroll bar to the floating table of contents in RMarkdown, such that if I want to jump to a later header in the document I can just click on the header of that section and jump to it. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Rmarkdown Cookbook](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-scroll.html) and using a little bit of HTML/CSS, we get the selector of the TOC, and then add some inline CSS, you can change the `max-height`(and probably `max-width`) to meet your needs.

*CSS*

````
```{css}
html body.preload div.container-fluid.main-container div.row div.col-md-2 div#toc
{
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  background-color: inherent;
  }
```
````

Which gives us your scrollable TOC

[image]

entire R code

````
---
author: Daniel
title: "R"
output:
  rmdformats::html_clean:
    highlight: haddock
    toc: TRUE
    toc_depth: 3
    toc_float: TRUE
    number_sections: TRUE
    thumbnails: FALSE
    code_folding: show
    df_print: paged
    DT: datatable
---

```{css}
html body.preload div.container-fluid.main-container div.row div.col-md-2 div#toc
{
max-height: 200px;
overflow-y: auto;
background-color: inherent;
}
```

# Chapter 1
# Chapter 2
# Chapter 3
# Chapter 4
# Chapter 5
# Chapter 6
# Chapter 7
# Chapter 8
````

You may already know, but the regular `html_document` with your same YAML settings will give you a scrollable TOC if the display is not large enough to display the entire TOC.

[image]